# Backing up Azure VM VHDs

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Planning on using Azure's VMs to host SQL and IIS. Not using local storage but the geo-redundant storage.

What's the best solution to backup this environment? Copy the VHDs locally?

I'm planning on transferring the drives into something I could mount in Hyper-V? Is that possible? Happy to buy a product if required.

Answer (score 2):

The persistent disks of a VM are stored in blob storage. This means you can leverage features like taking snapshots of these disks (blobs).

In order to create snapshots you can use the REST API, the [.NET SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblob.createsnapshot.aspx) or even [Cerebrata’s Cloud Storage Studio](http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/taking-vhd-snapshot-with-windows-azure-virtual-machines/). If you ever need the backup you can download the snapshot and mount it in Hyper-V.

Comment: is there any solution that can snapshot and copy automatically or scheduled?

Comment: Taking a snapshot is indeed a very handy way of doing so, I've blogged about it in the past -http://yossidahan.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/taking-vhd-snapshot-with-windows-azure-virtual-machines/, when I received a very useful comment - you really ought to make sure the VMs are off when you take the snapshot or you risk losing the contents of the memory as well as the host thinking the machine was not stopped properly when you boot off the backup.

Comment: As for scheduling - there is an API for it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691971.aspx) so it's just a case of wrapping it up in something and running on a schedule, ideally from outside the machine, obviously necessary if you're planning to shut it down